# Angular test with asyncScheduler and flush - why it fails with flush()?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-test

There is this Angular component:

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { asyncScheduler, Observable, of, queueScheduler, scheduled } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-component',
  templateUrl: './test-component.component.html'
})
export class TestComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  value: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const data$ = this.fetchDataScheduler();

    data$
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.value = value;
      });
  }

  private fetchDataScheduler(): Observable<string> {
    return scheduled(of('foo'), asyncScheduler);
  }

}
```

and the test is failing:

```js
it('async - test setTimeout', fakeAsync(() => {
    expect(component.value).toBeFalsy();

    fixture.detectChanges(); // ngOnInit

    expect(component.value).toBeFalsy();
    flush();

    expect(component.value).toBe('foo');  // <- fails here
  }));
```

[image: failing test]

`flush()` should flush all macrotasks, but it does not. Why? 
If I use `tick()`, then the test is passing.

[image: passing test]

(Screenshots above provided by Jest and Wallaby plugin.)

Why is not passing with `flush()` but is passing with `tick()`?

[flush](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/flush):

> Simulates the asynchronous passage of time for the timers in the fakeAsync zone by draining the macrotask queue until it is empty. The returned value is the milliseconds of time that would have been elapsed.

Repo is here: https://stackblitz.com/github/felikf/angular-testing-examples

Comment: Can you setup a stackblitz reproducing the problem? Based on the documentation, the `tick()` without arguments is a `flush()` command. https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-async-service

Comment: I am working on it: https://stackblitz.com/github/felikf/angular-testing-examples, it kind of works. It is possible to clone from github also.

Comment: Reported as bug: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34742

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**asyncScheduler** is a `setInterval` which is a periodic *macroTask*, and currently the **flush() API only flush non-periodic macroTasks such as setTimeout()**

For now you should use *tick()* to make it work.

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34742#issuecomment-597259879)

Comment: See [here](https://medium.com/@felix.fatka/thanks-for-the-response-43c4d7acb46c) and [here](https://netbasal.medium.com/by-default-the-internal-flush-method-flushes-only-non-periodic-tasks-cf0239def42c) - the referenced issue is mine, I have just forgotten to update answer, **thank you for it**.